# stochastic hill-climbing search

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working on defining a  stochastic hill-climbing search function using Python.This is my code below.

```
def guess():  
    return np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 4) 
    
def neighbour(x):    
    return np.random.uniform(-10, 9.3, 4)
    
    
def hill_climbing(l, max_iters, guess_fn, neighbour_fn):    
    best_guess=None
    best_loss=None
    
    guess = guess_fn()
    loss = l(guess)
        
    if best_loss is None or l(guess)<best_loss:
        best_loss = l(guess)
        best_guess = guess
    
    for i in range(max_iters):
        proposal = neighbour_fn(best_guess)
        loss_p=l(proposal)
         
        if best_guess is None or l(proposal)<best_loss:
            best_loss=l(proposal)
            best_guess=proposal
           
    return best_guess
```

However ,when i was trying to test it using the code below, it did not pass.This test required the loss less than 0.1 ,however ,i have tried using lots of value in neighbour function which actually will make change to the one in guess function.

```
np.random.seed(2018)
    passed = True
    for i in range(10):
        target = np.random.uniform(0,4,4)
        # use a random target :)
        def custom_l(theta):
            return np.sum((theta-target)**2)          
        # 5000 iterations
        result = hill_climbing(custom_l, 5000, guess, neighbour)
        difference = custom_l(result)               
        print("Loss on run {i} is {loss:.2e}".format(i=i, loss=difference))        
        if difference>0.1:
            passed = False        
    assert(passed)
```

Is there any problem with my functions ,because i cannot really figure out it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you aren't doing any actual climbing. You're just making random guesses using the neighbor function and checking them. Climbing would require generating random *steps* and adding them to the current best guess.

I gather that must be why `neighbour` takes a parameter (`x`). It's supposed to generate a *neighbor* of the point `x` by generating a random step and *adding* it to `x`. But again, the one you show here doesn't generate a neighbor, it always just generates a completely random value, by default between `-10` and (for some odd reason) `9.3`. So it can't learn anything at all!

Based on your comments, you'll also need to use much, much smaller numbers than `-10` and `10` in the `neighbour` function.

Comment: Hi,thank you fo your help. But I am not sure about the way of generating the neighbor if you could make it clearer. i have tried the np.random.uniform(-10,10,4) (like the one in guess function ,because i am supposed to get  vectors between -10 and 10 with 4 elements) +x.But it still did not work.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I tried that too, and it did work. Keep in mind that you'll have to adjust the values you're passing to `numpy.random.uniform` as well. Remember that the value you're adding to `x` is a *step*. When you are climibng a hill do you expect to climb the hill in one giant step? Or lots of small steps?

Comment: I understand .But the thing is I have  to change the values i am passing to numpy.random.uniform ,but they all didn not work. So i am just wondering if it correct to just make changes to the values  though I have added x behind.

Comment: Why don't you add the new code to the bottom of your answer, with the smallest values you tried.

Comment: Like because the neighbour will just make small changes to  the guess , i used np.random.uniform(-10, 5, 4) +x

Comment: That's a huge change to the guess. It's a random number between -10 and 5. Those will often be huge steps — just a few could take you way outside the -10, 10 range. Remember you are **adding these numbers together many times**.

Comment: Thanks.But Are you talking about something like np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 4) +2*x ,or similar

Comment: No I'm talking about the numbers you're passing to no.random.uniform. You need to try numbers way, way smaller than -10 and 10. Like many many times smaller. See how small you can make those numbers. But also try drawing this process out by hand, with just two dimensions, X and Y — like draw a grid and place a random target on it and place an initial random guess, and then look what happens when you add a random number to both X and Y that is between -10 and 10, and do that five or six times. And then do the same with a random number between -1 and 1. And then try -0.1 and 0.1.